# How common is it for people who work in industry to be a reviewer for a journal?

Tags: journals, review-articles

How common is it for people who work in industry to be a reviewer for a journal? I know that most reviewers are academics, but it seems like some people may enjoy reviewing as a hobby if they are interested in a particular line of research and if it crosses with some of their work in industry.

Comment: In my field, many PhDs go to industry jobs. Some continue to publish and because of that they get manuscripts to review. In some cases, ppl from the industry contact editors of journal to provide review services.

Comment: @Alex, how are you defining "industry"? Industry certainly includes industrial research labs. Researchers at such labs are perhaps more likely to review (and maybe publish) than other areas of industry.